# How to add inserted/updated/deleted entries to Entity Framework DbContext on table insert from different application?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, .net-core

I have a .net console app that reads from a SQL Server database.

Different app inserts/updates/deletes a row in the table -> my console app is subscribed to this event(s) and adds/updates/removes the entity in its' context.

I know there is a possibility of using after insert trigger, but I'd love to handle this in the code somehow.

Comment: What do you mean by "reloading the dbcontext"? Do you want an insert event and load this new row in your app? Or are you looking for some specific implementation? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me.

Comment: @Jerodev yes, sorry I will re-phrase it.

Comment: have you looked at [Query Notifications in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server)? support for it was implemented for .net core 2.1

Comment: In the simpliest terms you want to implement some sort of tracer something like SQL Server Profiler does?